# ImageJ returning all pixels in rgb format from an imagestack slice

Tags: java, pixel, rgb, imagej

I have the code below and it compiles fine. I've done some debugging and it is able to recognise the image file, see the dimensions, and how many slices through the getDimensions() method. However, when I try and use the getPixel(x,y) method. It keeps giving me back an all 0 array. My image is not all black.

I'm not sure what is going on. But I could use some help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test{

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

    try{
        ArrayList<Integer> totalWhitePixels = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        ArrayList<Integer> totalYellowPixels = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        ArrayList<Integer> totalBluePixels = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 


        //read image file
        ImagePlus img = new ImagePlus("C:\\Image74.tif");


        for(int n=1; n<=img.getNSlices(); n++){
            img.setSlice(n);
            int whitePixelCount = 0;
            int yellowPixelCount = 0;
            int bluePixelCount = 0;
            int testPixelCount = 0;
            //write file
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\log.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);


            //find pixel colors
            for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
                    int[] c = img.getPixel(x,y);

                    //testPixel
                    if (c[0]==0 && c[1]==0 && c[2]==0 && c[3]==0){
                        testPixelCount++;
                    }


                    //whitePixel
                    if (c[0]> 240 && c[1]> 240 && c[2]> 240) {
                            whitePixelCount++;
                    }
                    //yellowPixel
                    if (c[0]> 240 && c[1]> 240 && c[2]> 0){
                        yellowPixelCount++; 
                    }
                    //bluePixel
                    if (c[0]> 0 && c[1]> 0 && c[2]> 240){
                            bluePixelCount++;
                    }
                }
            }

            //System.out.println(whitePixelCount + "." + yellowPixelCount + "." + bluePixelCount);
            //System.out.println(testPixelCount);

            totalWhitePixels.add(whitePixelCount);
            totalYellowPixels.add(yellowPixelCount);
            totalBluePixels.add(bluePixelCount);
        }
    }


    catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: So, I don't think I was too clear in the message above. 

Basically the .tiff file is a stack of rgb images.
I want to analyze all the pixels from every slice and count the colors white, blue, and yellow.

This code goes through slices and goes through every pixel in each slice. But the pixel value it returns is 0, 0, 0. Which is not the color in the image.

What is this even.

Comment: I tested your code using both `IJ.openImage(String)` and `new ImagePlus(String)` with a single-plane RGB PNG file, and it works. Perhaps ImageJ is not reading your TIFF correctly? Are you able to open it using the ImageJ GUI and probe the pixel values using the mouse cursor (look in status bar of main window for pixel readouts)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`IJ.openImage(java.lang.String path)`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html?ij/IJ.html) instead of `new ImagePlus("C:\\Image74.tif")`, as suggested in Fiji's [tips for developers](http://fiji.sc/Tips_for_developers#Using_ImageJ_effectively). You can find more developer resources [here](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/index.html), and you can always ask on the [imagej mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html).

Comment: Hmmmm, after replacing it with your line of code. It still gives me the same problem of returning [0,0,0,0] for my int[] c array.

I tried replacing the file with a completely red single slice tif file and still it gives me [0,0,0,0].

Comment: I have tried it with a tiff, jpg, and gif file. From the getDimensions method I see that the file is being read in. But is it just reading a black image?